# HIVE QL to GCP BIGQUERY SQL MIGRATION

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-bigquery

We are planning to migrate from Cloudera Onprem to GCP soon. I would like to hear from experts in rearchitecting HIVE Query Language to Bigquery SQL. Will it require additional development efforts? and What are the best practices to be followed? Thanks

Comment: Depends on exactly what features of Hive you using and what SQL functions etc. I don't think anyone can give you conclusive answer there. BigQuery supports external table from GCS but not using custom serde. Anything else and you can run Hive inside DataProc no problems.

Comment: It's a true migration project. You must analyse each query and translate them in SQL. Most of the SQL will be the same. Some specific functions, or app dependent functions (such as metadata query) will be different. Few rework, redesign could be required in few corner cases.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could share your HiveQL scripts/queries then people might be better able to advise,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.